# How display images properly with jquery jcarousel

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi i am using jquery jCarousel for displaying images but problem is that i have set its property  visible :4

```
              {
    btnPrev: null,
    btnNext: null,
    btnGo: null,
    mouseWheel: false,
    auto: null,

    speed: 200,
    easing: null,

    vertical: false,
    circular: true,
    visible: 4,
    start: 0,
    scroll: 1,

    beforeStart: null,
    afterEnd: null
}
```

It is displaying images only if there are 4 images exist.If there are less than 4 images than it display nothing how i can achive this functionality to display any number of images less than 4 without setting its visible property.

Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the JS files properly?